# Update DOM object in time intervals using JavaScript Worker

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to do some DOM objects updates in background.

What I mean is update tab title, and some elements regardless if user has tab active or not ( to show that there are new notifications )

I already found out, that Worker has to be used as it runs in background ( but don't have access to DOM). Tried as follows:

Main HTML:

```
...some html

<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (window.Worker) {
        console.log('[DEBUG] Worker is supported')
        var eventsWorker = new Worker("<c:url value="/resources/js/eventTimer.js" />");
        setInterval(eventsWorker.postMessage([appUrl]), 20 * 1000);
        //setEventsNonWorker()
        eventsWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log('Message received from worker' + e.data);
            setEventsCount(e.data, appName, eventsTxt);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('[DEBUG] Worker is NOT supported')
        setEventsNonWorker()
    }
});
function setEventsNonWorker(){
    //regular update with setTimout and stuff
}
```

worker javascript file

```
function setEventsCount(count, appName, eventsTxt) {
    var bell, text, countPar;
    if (count > 0) {
        bell = '<i class="fa fa-bell"></i>&nbsp;';
        countPar = '(' + count + ') ';
       text = bell + eventsTxt + countPar;
       $(".event-menu-li").html(text);
       $("#event-menu-icon").html(bell + count)
       document.title = countPar + appName;
    } else {
       bell = '<i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>&nbsp;';
       text = bell + eventsTxt;
       $(".event-menu-li").html(text);
       $("#event-menu-icon").html(bell)
       document.title = appName;
    }
}

onmessage = function (e) {
    var appUrl = e.data[0];
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            postMessage(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", appUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The first call is working ( the event count is properly set ) but there are no more calls in 20 sec

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out I was putting timeout in wrong place

html should be

```
//...    
eventsWorker.postMessage([appUrl]);
eventsWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker' + e.data);
    setEventsCount(e.data, appName, eventsTxt);
//...
```

which will just init worker , while worker.js should have the timeout

```
//...
onmessage = function (e) {
    var appUrl = e.data[0];
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            postMessage(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", appUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    setInterval(function () {
        xmlhttp.open("GET", appUrl, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }, 20*1000);
}
```